# Generic fibers of the Gauss map are linear spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

**Problem**

I'm currently working on a problem in *Cartan for Beginners* by J.M. Landsberg and Thomas Ivey (Exercise 2.5.4.3). This question is stated:

> Show that the generic fibers of the Gauss map are (open subsets of) linear spaces, and thus flat surfaces are ruled by lines.

I'm having a little trouble figuring out what the question is asking.

**Questions**

**1.** What does the question mean by "generic fibers of the Gauss map?" The Gauss map was defined in the text as the map taking $x$ to $e_3(x)$, where $x$ is an element of an oriented surface $M$, and $e_3$ the normal vector associated with an orthonormal moving frame $(e_1(x),e_2(x),e_3(x))$ for $M$.

From my understanding, the fiber of this map would simply be a collection of points in the manifold, (for example if $M$ is the sphere $S^2$, the the fiber of $(0,0,1)$ under the Gauss map would simply be $(0,0,1)$) but I don't see how this could possibly be a linear space, so I must be understanding incorrectly.

On the other hand, by "generic fiber of the Gauss map," he could be referring to the the fiber of the projection $(x,e_1,e_2,e_3)\mapsto e_3$, where $x\in M$ and $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ is an orthonormal frame associated with the point $x$. This would make more sense, but this makes showing that it is a linear space trivial (if by linear space he means vector space).

**2.** What does a "linear space" exactly mean? A vector space? A plane? a line?

**3.** what does ''generic" mean exactly? I believe this to be an algebraic geometry term, however it has not been defined anywhere in the text. Does this mean just the fiber of an arbitrary point?

Sorry if I seem dense by needing clarification on half the words in the statement of the problem, but I would like to know the exact question being asked. For a flat surface this problem seems to make sense, because for a cylinder (for example) the collection of points having the same image under the gauss map makes a straight line. However for a sphere or something less trivial, it's just a singleton. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you also include the exercise? (Yes, in general the preimage of a Gauss map is not a linear space)

Comment: @JohnMa the exercise is the statement quoted. Is there any further information you would like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a bit glib of a statement. The case with which you started is fine — points are $0$-dimensional vector spaces. There is a high-dimensional version of this statement, but I'm assuming (I don't actually know this book, although I know its authors) that you're dealing just with surfaces. Try this statement: Suppose $M\subset\Bbb R^3$ is a flat surface ($K=0$) with no planar points. — Translation: The Gauss map has rank $1$ everywhere. — Then prove that the fibers of the Gauss map are open subsets of lines (affine $1$-dimensional subspaces of $\Bbb R^3$).

Here's a hint to get you started: Choose a moving frame $e_1,e_2,e_3$ with $e_1(x)$ giving a basis for $\ker de_3(x)$. [Note that by the constant rank assumption this makes sense.]

P.S. You could go bug one of the authors down the hall from you. :)

Comment: Thank you for your help! That clears up a lot. And you're right, I could go see Dr. Landsberg, but as it was a Saturday I was just greedy and wanted instant answers!